# Plot .shp file on google map using java script

Tags: c#, javascript, google-maps

How to plot a .shp file on google map?

I want to make a layer using .shp file. But i don't find any solution. I find how to plot kml file.

```
function initialize() {
            var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(28.4433713, 77.1086040);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 11,
                center: chicago
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/realtek_poc_m9/inspectionresults-33ca`enter code here`f635-d66c-4c22-a92b-16e4292ef47d/a.kml'
        });
        ctaLayer.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: One option: [import shapefiles into FusionTables](http://www.shpescape.com/ft/)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your .shp file to a kml file using a programs such as [qgis](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) (which is free to download) and then use the code you have posted above.

As far as I am aware it is not possible to plot a .shp file using the javascript api.

Be careful to set your projection correctly during the conversion (spherical mercator).